# Captcha code makes all html elements disappear on jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, captcha

i got this java captcha code: http://codepaste.net/a4vxzh
I want to put the image the code generates in my jsp page, but when I write the code anywhere in the page, only the image appears and everything thats supposed to be on the page disappears. I thought about writing the html elemenets inside the code using pirnt.out, but I'm sure there is a better way that I can not think of. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that code you stole [ ;) ] is writing to your output I guess..
its supposed to be called as a different request and not to be included in your code..
keep it running individually, don't include it in your code.. when you require to show a captcha, enclose it in a well defined container like div or iframe and request it from there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction, but how can I call the code from another jsp ? It doesn't seem to have a return, it just produces an image and puts in the page. So i think there is a way to call an entire jsp page ? or should I try to modify the code so it returns an image ?

Comment: I meant to run it as a separate jsp, which has its own request response.. I didn't mean to "call" its functions..  I meant to say, when you want to show the captcha, make a new request through iframe or something similar to this jsp.

Comment: @Tunca Ersoy : you could as well select this as accepted answer :) you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You should really use a wide-used captcha system, instead of a custom one. Many links point to the fact that captcha using circles or things like that to obscure the text are not a very good way to do it (see for example [here](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha)).

Use [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) instead, it's wide-used, secure, and easy to use. Plus, it rocks, and helps to numerize old books. [Here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/recaptcha/docs/java.html) is how to use it with Java/JSP.

Comment: I would prefer  recaptcha also, but my boss/teacher wants the contents of the captcha to be modifiable, and not require to be connected to an external server.

Comment: Self-made captchas are really insecure. Can't you point him to the links I gave you, in order for him to see that it's not a good way to go ?